# Sort Dictionary (string, int) by value

Tags: c#, sorting

So basically I'm having an issue with the task I've been given. I won't bore you with the details of the task itself so I'll just give you the relevant info.

I have a dictionary that I need to be sorted by the int[value] that is the highest, well the top five highest to be precise and I need to be able to show the bottom five as well.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

The strings(keys) hold words that have been read for a text file. The ints (values) hold ints of how many times they were mentioned in the document.

I was going to do it in another way but I was told to do it with a dictionary so please dictionary only help.
I would appreciate it if you can explain how it should be done so I can learn as well as complete the task as the aim of the task is to educate myself but I'm finding it a bit hard..

I appreciate all your help in advance, if more info is required please let me know and I'll post it!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Dictionaries do not have any inherent order. But if you want to get the top 5 entries with highest (or lowest) values, you can use a little Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var top5 = dict.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).Take(5);
var bottom5 = dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value).Take(5);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`. To turn it back into a dictionary, again Linq can help. For example:

```
var top5 = dict.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).Take(5)
               .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Now, `top5` is a `Dictionary<string, int>` which contains only the 5 elements from `dict` with  the hightest value.

Comment: Comment to everyone: Thanks so much for the help! Also, I was wondering what => means, the description on msdn is a little bit confusing for a novice like myself.

Comment: @user3245390 That's a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). `pair => pair.Value` creates an anonymous method which accepts a single parameter, `pair`, and returns `pair.Value`.

Comment: Why not just use a SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GDB From MSDN, the `SortedDictionary`, "*Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted on the **key**.*" -- OP wants to sort the results based on the value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get ordered result from your dictionary, Since you are looking for Top 5, you will need `Take` like:

```
//Top 5
foreach (var item in dict.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value).Take(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

The reason you need an OrderBy is because:

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. **The order in which the items are returned is undefined.**

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **C# 3.0 and higher**

You can do something like this with `LINQ`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> item in keywordCounts.OrderBy(key=> key.Value).Take(5))
{ 
    // do something with item.Key and item.Value
}
```

If you are using **C# 2.0**

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = aDictionary.ToList();

myList.Sort((firstPair,nextPair) =>
    {
        return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
);
```

or it can be rewritten as

```
myList.Sort((x,y)=>x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
```

`LINQ` allows for great flexibility in that you can select the top 10, 20 10% etc. Or if you are using your word frequency index for type-ahead, you could also include StartsWith clause as well.